# Handling old configuration section without appropriate reader type and XML reading techniques

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configurationmanager

I have many configuration sections left by an old application:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MySection" 
             type="AppV1.MySectionReader, AppV1" />
  </configSections>
  <MySection>
    <!-- fields -->
  </MySection>
</configuration>
```

I can't change the config file structure by compatibility reasons (old app is still working). Also I can't re-use old application libraries (for sanitary reasons).

I want to access and change the config in a safest and easiest way. Preferably, using a .NET framework. I know I can use xml readers, but in my case there's a lot of sections (and section groups), and implementing an own nice framework for all cases is an overkill (does anyone already did that?).

Also, I can't believe Microsoft didn't think about this kind of problems.

So, how you would deal with that?

**UPD**: `Configuration.TypeStringTransformer`, `Configuration.AssemblyStringTransformer` callbacks did not help (not being fired).

**UPD-2**: If you still think that handmade xml parsing is simple in this case, think about such configuration features as config section grouping, config file embedding and merging, section protection. And I'm not looking for a problems, it is the requirement in my case.

Comment: I don't understand the scenario. Why would you ever be forced to use a .config file that's no longer compatible with your application?

Comment: Because I'm writing an installer/configurator tool for that old application.

Comment: Not clear to me what you need to change. An example would clarify a lot.

Comment: For example, I need to change a value here `<MySection someName="valueToChange">`. But as I said, If there's no framework/third-party tools support (by support I mean type safe access to a section), it's already a bad news. XmlDoc answer will not be accepted